# Load Another ViewController after Facebook Login with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, facebook-login

I'm trying to load another view controller after successful Facebook login with swift. I've been following this blog post: http://studyswift.blogspot.com.tr/2016/01/facebook-sdk-and-swift-create-facebook.html

I configured a segue named "**redirectAfterLogin**" and tried to use **performSegueWithIdentifier**

Below you can see my ViewController.swift and AppDelegate.swift files. Somehow I'm missing something. Any suggestions?

***ViewController.swift***

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        loginButton.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(loginButton)
        //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("redirectAfterLogin", sender: self)
        
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    
    
    /*
    func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result:FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
        if error == nil {
            print("login complete")
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("redirectAfterLogin", sender: self)
        }
        else {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        
    }
    */

}
```

***AppDelegate.swift***

```
import UIKit

import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FBSDKShareKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

And this is the output after I logged in in simulator:

> 2016-02-11 14:43:49.712 TMR-Prototype1[22260:3512428] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"
>
> 2016-02-11 14:43:49.717 TMR-Prototype1[22260:3512428] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"

And here's the screenshot. It stuck at first viewcontroller:
[image]

I also edited my Info.plist file as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    
    <!-- following stuff added by me as for facebook login -->
    
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fbXXXYYYZZZ</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>XXXYYYZZZ</string>
    
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>TMR</string>
    
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>facebook.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
            <key>fbcdn.net</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
            <key>akamaihd.net</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
    </array>
    
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should implement the `FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate` to your `ViewController`, and include the delegate methods.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        loginButton.center = view.center
        loginButton.delegate = self // Remember to set the delegate of the loginButton
        view.addSubview(loginButton)
    }

    func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
        /* 
           Check for successful login and act accordingly.
           Perform your segue to another UIViewController here.
        */
    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        // Actions for when the user logged out goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems I forgot to set delegate of login button. Thanks